# Accessing data from a struct from another class in with ostream

Tags: c++, struct, nodes, ostream

I am wanting to access the output of the nodes being created in my struct class.
Right now my code is saving names into each node.

node 1: Bob, Joe, Jill

node 2: Jeff, Andy, Kevin, Luis

node 3: Heather, Andy, Candy

However, I am trying to figure out how to output them from the ostream operator

```
struct node {
    node(string value="") {data=value; next=NULL; }

    string data;

    node *next;
};


class list {

public:
    list(int N=0, int value=0);
    ~list();

    friend ostream & operator << (ostream &, const list &);

private:
    int N;
    node *head;

};


ostream& operator << (ostream & out, const list & list_def)
{
//out << list_def.data;

}

int main(){
list names[3];

cout << names[0];

}
```

The names are being saved in **node** with **data** saving each name. As you can see, I tried doing list_def.data, but it doesn't output them. I feel like it would be something like list_def.node->data, but that is not working either.

Comment: You may want to enumerate that list, since you're going through the trouble of building it and all.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other problems, but this :

```
ostream& operator << (ostream & out, const list & list_def)
{
 node *ptr = head;
 while(ptr){
   out<<ptr->data;
   ptr=ptr->next;
 }
 return out;
}
```

would work if your constructor for `list` class is correctly defined.

Comment: He's overriding the insertion operator for a *list*. I'm somewhat confident he wants to insert *the list* and not just the head of said-list. Its the enumeration I think he's struggling with.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah agreed, and I think OP problem is a [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This is kinda working. It's giving LOTS of output. it's outputting jim, bob, jill, jim, jim, bob. I'm not very competent at programming, but would it be possible to maybe look at the head from the ostream operator and then keep going to next until it reaches null and then output?

Answer (score 1):

The `list` class doesn't have a `data` member, but the `node` class have. You have to access e.g. `head->data`.

Or rather, you probably should loop over the list starting at `head`, and print the current nodes `data` member. Like:

```
for (node* current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
    out << current->data;
```

Beware that you must initialize `head` in your constructor, or it will be an uninitialized pointer and cause undefined behavior when you dereference it.